# django-image-cropping does not show cropping tool in the admin

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make django-image-cropping to work. I did the following steps:

1. `pip install django-image-cropping`
2. **settings.py**

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
    [..]
   'easy_thumbnails',
   'image_cropping',
   ]
   [..]
   THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
   from easy_thumbnails.conf import Settings as thumbnail_settings
   THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
       'image_cropping.thumbnail_processors.crop_corners',
   ) + thumbnail_settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS
   ```
3. **models.py**

   ```
   class AboutImg(models.Model):
       image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True,
                                 upload_to='uploaded_images')
       cropping = ImageRatioField('image', '500x480')
   ```
4. **admin.py**

   ```
   class MyModelAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
       pass

   admin.site.register(AboutImg, MyModelAdmin)
   ```
5. **views.py**

   ```
   def about(request):
       aboutimg = AboutImg.objects.order_by('pub_date').first()
       context = {'aboutimg': aboutimg}
       return render(request, 'about.html', context)`
   ```
6. **about.html**

   ```
   {% load cropping %}

   <img src="{% cropped_thumbnail aboutimg "cropping" %}"   
        class="img-responsive wooimg" alt="{{aboutimg.title}}"
        title="{{aboutimg.title}}" />
   ```

when I create a new istance of object `AboutImg` in the admin, the `cropping` field looks like that:
[image: cropping fails!]

When I save the instance of `AboutImg` in the admin panel, I've also noticed that in my `upload_images/` folder two more images are created from the base image `05_2.jpg`:

- 05_2_l3l0SL7.jpg
- 05_2_l3l0SL7.jpg.1425x500_q85_detail_upscale.jpg

and if I open the instance just created in the admin, now the base image is no more `05_2.jpg` but `05_2_l3l0SL7.jpg`.

[image]

I've checked all the stackoverflow questions about this subject, but none of the answers are ok with me.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT1: my env

```
 `pip freeze >  
  Django==1.8.3
  Pillow==4.0.0
  appdirs==1.4.0
  django-appconf==1.0.1
  django-image-cropping==1.0.4
  django-taggit==0.22.0
  easy-thumbnails==2.3
  olefile==0.44
  packaging==16.8
  pyparsing==2.1.10
  six==1.10.0
  wsgiref==0.1.2'
```

The JS console at /admin says

[image: jsconsole]

Comment: Which version of `django`  and `django-image-cropping` are you using?
Are there any JS-Errors showing up in the Console?

Comment: @arie: I edited the question with he requested info, thank you!

Comment: Your problem sounds similar to these: https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping/issues/78

Is the `image_cropping.js` properly loaded in your admin?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're serving media files correctly? Since it isn't active by default in django development mode..
Try this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 0):

Have you the correct path in settings.py ?

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/your/local/path//media/'
```

and you have in urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:  
        urlpatterns += patterns('',  
                                #REMOVE IT in production phase  
                                (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  
                                {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
          )
```